# Does bool_and short-circuit function calls with arguments?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, functions, aggregate

Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
GROUP BY a.id -- Primary key
HAVING bool_and(expensive_comparison(a, b))
```

What will PostgreSQL do with this query? Will it process `expensive_comparison` on all pairs, or will it stop and return immediately for a given for a given `a.id`?

Is there a more efficient, equivalent way to write this query without resorting to procedural code?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3, but if it's changed in any newer versions, that would be relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the funciton is `IMMUTABLE` or not. All tests done on PostgreSQL 9.5.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_expensive_volatile ()
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT true
  FROM pg_sleep(1)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
VOLATILE;

CREATE FUNCTION f_expensive_stable ()
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT true
  FROM pg_sleep(1)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
STABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION f_expensive_immutable ()
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT true
  FROM pg_sleep(1)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now we create sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE f AS
SELECT 1 AS id, *
FROM generate_series(1,100) AS gs(x);
```

Now on the `IMMUTABLE` one, note `Execution time: 0.138 ms`,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT id
  FROM f
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING bool_and( f_expensive_immutable() );

                                             QUERY PLAN                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=2.50..2.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.083..0.083 rows=1 loops=1)
   Group Key: id
   Filter: bool_and(true)
   ->  Seq Scan on f  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.030 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1001.328 ms
 Execution time: 0.138 ms
(6 rows)
```

And on the `STABLE` one...  note `me not waiting around`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT id
  FROM f
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING bool_and( f_expensive_stable() );
```

And also this exemplifies me not waiting around...

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT id
  FROM f
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING bool_and( f_expensive_volatile() );
```

## With arguments

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_expensive_immutable (int)
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT true
  FROM pg_sleep(1)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT id
  FROM f
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING bool_and( f_expensive_immutable(id) );
```

Yes, it seems that optimization is lost if you provide arguments

Comment: First of all, thanks! Second, hm. Your functions never return `false`, so I'm not sure why they would short circuit even if PostgreSQL does so. I notice your functions don't have any inputs. Could that affect the optimization?

Comment: @jpmc26 my tests seem to show that the optimizations are lost if arguments are present looking into it now

Comment: Still a little confused about how your examples could be optimized. There's also only one row per group, so there's no actual and-ing together. The functions always return `true`, too, which means each row would have to be evaluated since there's no `false` to immediately conclude `bool_and` should be `false`.

Comment: Each row doesn't have to be evaluated, because the funciton is marked as `IMMUTABLE`. So if f(x) = true. What do you get f(x) AND f(x)? (true)... Thus the optimization